# Gouy-Chapman model

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions, electrolysis

Recently I have been investigating the problem of a neutral solutions (with equal number of anions and cations) interacting with an infinite surface $z=0$ with electrostatic potential $\phi(z=0)=\phi_0>0$.

If we assume only one type of cation and anion, with opposite charges, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2\phi\left(\textbf{r}\right)=-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\sum_{i=1}^{2}q_{i}n_{i}\left(\textbf{r}\right)
\end{equation}
with $q_1=-q_2=q$. If we assume that the density of charges is in thermal equlibrium, we have through Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution
\begin{equation}
n_{i}\left(\textbf{r}\right)=n_{i}^{0}e^{-\frac{q_{i}\phi\left(\textbf{r}\right)}{k_{B}T}}.
\end{equation}

After manipulating a bit, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2\phi\left(\textbf{r}\right)=2qn_{0}\sinh\left[\frac{q\phi\left(\textbf{r}\right)}{k_{B}T}\right],
\end{equation}
which describes the very famous Gouy-Chapman model
with analytical solution given by
\begin{equation}
\phi\left(z\right)=2\frac{k_{B}T}{q}\ln\left[\frac{1+\tanh\left(\frac{qW}{4k_{B}T}\right)e^{-z/\lambda_{D}}}{1-\tanh\left(\frac{qW}{4k_{B}T}\right)e^{-z/\lambda_{D}}}\right]
\end{equation}
and anion (-), cation (+) densities given by
\begin{equation}
n_{\pm}\left(z\right)=n_{0}\left[\frac{1+\tanh\left(\frac{qW}{4k_{B}T}\right)e^{-z/\lambda_{D}}}{1-\tanh\left(\frac{qW}{4k_{B}T}\right)e^{-z/\lambda_{D}}}\right]^{\mp2}
\end{equation}, where I plot for different positive values of $\phi_0$
[image]

**Contradiction:** As we can clearly see from figure above, the neutrality condition does not hold anymore -- see imbalance between positive and negative charges. People from this field argue that there is no problem since a surface charged density was absorbed by the plate (positive surface charged if $_0>0$). However, how do we see this physically? I do not understand why positive charges were absorbed by the plate. Can we somehow show this mathematically? If we integrate the total density $\rho(z)$, we will not obtain zero, implying there is no charge neutrality within the problem.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: The plate was _charged_ in the first place. The imbalance of cations vs anions in the solution neutralizes that charge.

Comment: The surface charge is the origin of the non-zero surface potential $\phi_0$. Since it is positive anions are more attracted to the surface than cations.

Comment: Look for a relation between the surface charge density and the z potential at the surface, and evaluate what the surface charge density corresponding to the potential you used in your calc might be. The net countercharge density in solution should be opposite this.

Comment: @IvanNeretin it seems this is not quite right. If we have $\phi>0$, this implies in a positively charged plate. However, the bulk solution has an excess of **negatively** charged atoms rather than positive ones. So it seems the consistence remains.

Comment: @BuckThorn As I wrote previously, if we have a positively charged plate with $\phi>0$, we would have an excess of negative charges within the solution. This implies that more positive charges 'moved out of the solution'. So it seems the consistence is still present.

Comment: That's right: a positively charged plate is surrounded by the negatively charged solution. That's what the word "neutralize" means.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Right! But this seems to be leading to an inconsistency. 
If the plate is positively charged, and assuming we started with a neutral solution, how can the solution have more negative charges after having them surrounding the positively charged surface?

Comment: The solution has as many negative charges as it had before, that is, exactly as many as positive ones. The layer around the plate has an excess of negative charges. See where this is going?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I am not sure I agree with this statement. The concentration of negative charges is larger than the positive one throughout the whole solution. So where is this imbalance coming from? Another way to put it: if we integrate the charge density over the volume of the solution, we will obtain a non-zero value, indicating the presence of a net charge different from zero.

Comment: There are models, and then there is reality. The picture is of the model that was deduced in assumption of infinite vessel with solution, bounded on one side with infinite charged plate. Is the model any good for a real, finite vessel? Yes and no. Yes for the layer near the plate, and no otherwise.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I understand what you mean, but I am not talking about reality here. 
We first started with Boltzmann and Poisson's equation for a neutral solution. After solving the corresponding equations, we obtain a charge density profile with net charge different from zero. The obvious questions is: where does this charge come from?

Comment: This charge comes from far away. In an infinite medium filled with charges, the law of charge conservation does not hold.